# twilio login - where do I get the secret?

Tags: linux, twilio

I am trying to learn how Twilio works, and uppon login I should login to the service and save that secret for usage in Android. See https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/android/get-started#bullet3

However - its not documented how to read that secret. On linux its saved using libsecret - which has a command line tool to read (`libsecret-common` contains a command line called `secret-tool), however its not documented how the secret is stored there (so retrieval is not trivial). Windows has a similar problem.

So: where do I get the secret generated at login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you can't find the api key and secret that are saved as part of the Twilio CLI, you can create another set of keys for your application. [Open up the Twilio console here](https://www.twilio.com/console/video/project/api-keys) and create a new API key and secret and you can use those values.

Comment: I am missing something. That screen links to my api keys, in which I can see the SID ... the `secret` part is still a mystery to me.

Comment: Yep, the secret isn't shown after the first time you create it. So you just need to create a new key and secret and use them in your app instead.

Comment: That is the exact question I am asking: when I create the API key, where do I get that secret? (On Windows and Linux).

Comment: When you create a new key, [you will see the key and secret as in this screenshot linked here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoGTX.png).

Comment: yeap, when you create the api key from the web interface it does show it... however the docs tell to generate this on the CLI... and I am still trougling to understand how to read it on Linux or Windows.. documentation is not strong here (on mac its easy to read from the keychain)

Comment: My point is that you do not need to read the credentials you generated for the CLI. The CLI will continue to use them to access the Twilio API on your behalf, but you can create and use other credentials to continue the tutorial. I will raise this with the tutorial author though, as it may be that they were only testing on a Mac and didn't realise the difficulty this instruction would cause on windows/linux.